# PHP Error prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php

I have this error in PHP:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\BookStore\user.php on line 21

This is the connect class where I connect to my DB:

```
<?php
 class Connection
{
public function dbConnect()
{
    return new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=msm41","root","");
}
}

?>
```

This is my user class where i try to check for login stuff:

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');

class User
{
private $db;
public function construct()
{//just like c# creating an object of the connection class
//and calling the connection function.connection is return by calling
//dbConnect.
    $this->db=new connection();
    $this->db=$this->db->dbConnect();

}
//------------------------------login-------------------------------------------
public function Login($id,$pass)
{
    if(!empty($id)&&!empty($pass))
    {
        //parameter query
        $st=$this->db->prepare("select * from customers where C_ID=? and C_PWD=?");
        $st->bindParam(1,$id);
        $st->bindParam(2,$pass);
        $st->execute();
        if($st->rowCount()==1)
        {
            echo"acces granted";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"incorect username or password";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo"please enter your id and a password";
    }
}
//----------------------------login----------------------------------------------
}
?>
```

I have been searching and found a lot of people with the same error. What I understood is that maybe my PDO is not visible but I don't think that is the case as I am returning and saving that PDO object.

Comment: Connection u assigned to $this->db in construct is not available in login();  try using __construct() :

Comment: already did. thanks for the help =]

Comment: Hi there. We don't mark questions as `[solved]` here, though thanks for wanting to do so. The best way to do that here is to accept an existing answer, or to make your own with the solution, and accept that.

Comment: Thanks for the info .. sorry i am new to this =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->db is set to a `Connection` object, which only has a `dbConnect()` method. Also, `construct()` is not a magic method and will not be called automatically on construction. `__construct()` is what you are looking for.

Why not just create a new PDO object as $this->db? The extra class is unnecessary.

Comment: woow ok that worked man thanks a lot. the problim was construct() not really sure what is a magic method.. gona go read about it thanks again m8.